# Getting records with highest level from SQL result set

Tags: sql

Probably not the best title but the following example will explain everything: 
I have a result set that comes back looking like this:

```
TargetID     CategoryID   ListID         Level
--------     ----------   ------         ----
104          8            29             5
104          8            37             5
104          8            7              3
104          8            7              3
```

I need to get the closest (highest level) lists of a certain category. The level could be any number. In other words, i need to return a unique set of TargetID/CategoryID/ListID but with the highest level.
So the filtered result should contain:

```
TargetID     CategoryID   ListID         Level
--------     ----------   ------         ----
104          8            29             5
104          8            37             5
```

Comment: Can you post the query that gets your resultset?

Comment: This is a select over a view. The view cannot be changed since it is used in other places

Comment: The other 3 columns are pretty obvious, but if these values are independent from one another, why both the 37 and 29 of `ListID`?

Comment: @paqogomez: There can be multiple lists under a category attached to my target. I need only the option lists that are attached on the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

Going to guess that you mean highest level within each ListID.  If that's the case, then here is SQL to rank the rows based on level, and then the outer query filters to the top hits (in this case, the highest level).

```
SELECT TargetID, CategoryID, ListID, Level
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    TargetID, CategoryID, ListID, Level,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ListID ORDER BY Level DESC) AS LevelRank
  FROM ...
  ) Ranked
WHERE Ranked.LevelRank = 1
```

More on the guts:

- PARTITION BY set to ListID makes it so that our ranking is set independently for each ListID (e.g., if ListID 14's highest level was 4, we'd keep that, even if some other ListID has a highest level of 5).  If you want it to be highest level globally (independent of ListIDs), then simply remove the "PARTITION BY ListID" piece
- ORDER BY defines the ranking order; in this case, highest Levels are ranked first.  In the case of multiple TargetIDs per level, this ranks them as a tie, and so both will be returned.  If you want to only get 1 row for each ListID, however, toss in ", TargetID" into the ORDER BY clause.

Here is a version of the query for if you want the highest level across all of the data (e.g., 5), and then just return any row with that level (same thing as above, but without the partitioning):

```
SELECT TargetID, CategoryID, ListID, Level
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    TargetID, CategoryID, ListID, Level,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Level DESC) AS LevelRank
  FROM ...
  ) Ranked
WHERE Ranked.LevelRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sqlFiddle I created. There are two seperate queries in the fiddle which may give you what you are asking for.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e8680/6/0

```
select * from test group by TargetId, CategoryId, ListId HAVING LEVEL = MAX(LEVEL);
```

This first query will return the rows for each targetId/CategoryId/ListId groups which has the max level for that grouping.

```
SELECT * from test group by TargetId, CategoryId, ListId HAVING LEVEL = (SELECT MAX(LEVEL) FROM test);
```

This second query will return the TargetId/CategoryId/ListId groups where the LEVEL is equal to the Maximum level within the table.